# Common function for validation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using simple code to validate whether input box is empty or not and just showing `check icon` and `warning icon` accordingly.

[image]

You can see working [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/ixCVzB53Eh4YasZUuiGU?p=preview) here.

*Problem*: This set of code works fine for one set of `Label:Input Box`.

Imagine if we have number of input control throughout the website.
I am looking for a solution which is quite generalized. No need to repeat same set of HTML, CSS or JS code over and over again.
I know its hard to avoid some duplication but wanna write less repetitive code.

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(

  function() {
    $("#icon-id").hide();
    $("#input-id").keyup(function() {
      if ($("#input-id").val().length === 0) {
        $("#input-id").addClass("redBorder");
        $("#icon-id").addClass("icon-warning-sign");
        $("#icon-id").removeClass("icon-check");
        $("#icon-id").css("color", "red");
        $("#icon-id").show();
      } else {
        $("#input-id").removeClass("redBorder");
        $("#icon-id").removeClass("icon-warning-sign");
        $("#icon-id").addClass("icon-check");
        $("#icon-id").css("color", "green");
        $("#icon-id").show();
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
  body {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  .input-container {
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .my-input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .my-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    color: red;
    top: 8px;
  }
  
  .redBorder {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.0.0-rc1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin-top:55px;">

  <!-- validation check -->
  <div id="header" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <div id="validate-click"><a href="#">Enter Below</a></div>
  </div>

  <!-- input contianre -->
  <div class="form-group input-container">
    <input id="input-id" type="text" class="my-input" placeholder="Enter here">
    <i id="icon-id" class="icon-warning-sign my-icon"></i>
  </div>

</html>
```

*Note: Please don't refer any third party control.*

Comment: Add a class or attach to each input (text) then for each one send through `this` and use that to control each one =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a jQuery plugin: https://jsfiddle.net/1nxtt0Lk/
I added the attribute data-validate to your `<input />`s so I can call the plugin on them using `$('[data-validate'])`.

Code:

```js
;( function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

 "use strict";

  var pluginName = "customValidator",
   defaults = {
    propertyName: "value"
   };

  function Plugin ( element, options ) {
   this.element = element;

   this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
   this._defaults = defaults;
   this._name = pluginName;
   this.init();
  }

  $.extend( Plugin.prototype, {
   init: function() {
       var $input = $(this.element);
       var $icon = $input.parent().find('.my-icon');
    $icon.hide();
        $input.keyup(function() {
          if ($input.val().length === 0) {
            $input.addClass("redBorder");
            $icon.addClass("icon-warning-sign");
            $icon.removeClass("icon-check");
            $icon.css("color", "red");
            $icon.show();
            console.log("empty");
          } else {
            $input.removeClass("redBorder");
            $icon.removeClass("icon-warning-sign");
            $icon.addClass("icon-check");
            $icon.css("color", "green");
            $icon.show();
            console.log("Not empty");
          }
        });
   },
  } );

  $.fn[ pluginName ] = function( options ) {
   return this.each( function() {
    if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
     $.data( this, "plugin_" +
      pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
    }
   } );
  };

} )( jQuery, window, document );

$('[data-validate]').customValidator();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  .input-container {
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .my-input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .my-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    color: red;
    top: 8px;
  }
  
  .redBorder {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.0.0-rc1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>
<div class="form-group input-container">
    <input id="input-id" type="text" class="my-input" placeholder="Enter here" data-validate>
    <i id="icon-id" class="icon-warning-sign my-icon"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group input-container">
    <input id="input-id2" type="text" class="my-input" placeholder="Enter here" data-validate>
    <i id="icon-id2" class="icon-warning-sign my-icon"></i>
 </div>
```

PS: I used the plugin boilerplate as a base script: https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate ;
a commented version can be found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/master/dist/jquery.boilerplate.js

Other answer suggest to use a class selector to iterate over each of them. Although that solution definitely would work, I suggest to get used to write jQuery plugins as in the long term it makes your project much more clean and easy to read.

Comment: Hi, I really like the concept of plugin. ur fiddle is working perfect. but when am moving fiddle code to plunker. its not working. I may b missing some part while moving. can u plz make plunker working. https://plnkr.co/edit/FzCarEuDk9JveuPEUc9s?p=preview

Comment: Since you're loading your scripts in the head, the html elements aren't there yet, so you're trying to initialize the plugin on non-existent elements. To fix this I wrapped the initialization in a $(document).ready() function that get's called when the whole DOM is loaded. https://plnkr.co/edit/8JUWuAuyfej0YrHTS8sR?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can use class selector instead id for the input. And use an data attribute to select the good icon.

[live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZZ3QqhGLIONEco3sqOef?p=preview)

You can see an example below :

```js
  function() {
    $(".icon-class").hide();
    $(".input-class").keyup(function() {
      var idIcon = $(this).attr('data-id-icon');
      if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $(this).addClass("redBorder");
        $("#" + idIcon).addClass("icon-warning-sign");
        $("#" + idIcon).removeClass("icon-check");
        $("#" + idIcon).css("color", "red");
        $("#" + idIcon).show();
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("redBorder");
        $("#" + idIcon).removeClass("icon-warning-sign");
        $("#" + idIcon).addClass("icon-check");
        $("#" + idIcon).css("color", "green");
        $("#" + idIcon).show();
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<input data-id-icon="icon-id-1" type="text" class="my-input input-class" placeholder="Enter here">
<i id="icon-id-1" class="icon-warning-sign my-icon"></i>
<input data-id-icon="icon-id-2" type="text" class="my-input input-class" placeholder="Enter here">
<i id="icon-id-2" class="icon-warning-sign my-icon-2"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(

  function() {
    $(".icon-id").hide();
    $(".input-id").keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $(this).addClass("redBorder");
        $(this.parentElement).find("#icon-id").addClass("icon-warning-sign");
        $(this.parentElement).find("#icon-id").removeClass("icon-check");
        $(this.parentElement).find("#icon-id").css("color", "red");
        $(this.parentElement).find("#icon-id").show();
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("redBorder");
        $(this.parentElement).find("#icon-id").removeClass("icon-warning-sign");
        $(this.parentElement).find("#icon-id").addClass("icon-check");
        $(this.parentElement).find("#icon-id").css("color", "green");
        $(this.parentElement).find("#icon-id").show();
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
  body {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  .input-container {
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .my-input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .my-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    color:red;
    top: 8px;
  }
  .redBorder{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.0.0-rc1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin-top:55px;">

  <!-- validation check -->
  <div id="header" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <div id="validate-click"><a href="#">Enter Below</a></div>
  </div>

  <!-- input contianre -->
  <div class="form-group input-container">
    <input id="input-id" type="text" class="my-input input-id" placeholder="Enter here">
    <i id="icon-id" class="icon-warning-sign my-icon icon-id"></i>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group input-container">
    <input id="input-id" type="text" class="my-input input-id" placeholder="Enter here">
    <i id="icon-id" class="icon-warning-sign my-icon icon-id"></i>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

You can try like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *classes* `my-input` and `my-icon` instead of the *id*s.

Inside the `keyup` listener you can use `$(this)` to refer to `my-input` and `$(this).next()` to refer to `my-icon` as the icon is the *adjacent sibling* of the `input`.

Also chain your functions like this for brevity:

```
$(this).next().removeClass("icon-warning-sign")
    .addClass("icon-check")
    .css("color", "green")
    .show();
```

See demo below:

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".my-icon").hide();
  $(".my-input").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
      $(this).addClass("redBorder");
      $(this).next().addClass("icon-warning-sign")
        .removeClass("icon-check")
        .css("color", "red")
        .show();
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("redBorder");
      $(this).next().removeClass("icon-warning-sign")
        .addClass("icon-check")
        .css("color", "green")
        .show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
.input-container {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.my-input {
  width: 100%;
}
.my-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  color: red;
  top: 8px;
}
.redBorder {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.0.0-rc1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body style="margin-top:55px;">

  <!-- validation check -->
  <div id="header" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <div id="validate-click"><a href="#">Enter Below</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- input contianre -->
  <div class="form-group input-container">
    <input id="input-id" type="text" class="my-input" placeholder="Enter here">
    <i id="icon-id" class="icon-warning-sign my-icon"></i>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: @ankitd your thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: thanks ... this sounds good and working perfect. as per answer by @Jonas am thinking of making a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $(".my-input").keyup(function() {
      var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
      var $icon = $(this).parent().find('i');
      if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $input.addClass("redBorder");
        $icon.addClass("icon-warning-sign").removeClass("icon-check").css("color", "red").show();
      } else {
        $input.removeClass("redBorder");
        $icon.removeClass("icon-warning-sign").addClass("icon-check").css("color", "green").show();
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
.input-container {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.my-input {
  width: 100%;
}
.my-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  color: red;
  top: 8px;
  display: none;
}
.redBorder {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.0.0-rc1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin-top:55px;">

  <!-- validation check -->
  <div id="header" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <div id="validate-click"><a href="#">Enter Below</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- input contianre -->
  <div class="form-group input-container">
    <input type="text" class="my-input" placeholder="Enter here">
    <i class="icon-warning-sign my-icon"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group input-container">
    <input type="text" class="my-input" placeholder="Enter here">
    <i class="icon-warning-sign my-icon"></i>
  </div>

</html>
```